# how to get my facebook share dialog to display the facebook share button rather than just text?

Tags: facebook, dialog, share

how to get my facebook share dialog to display the facebook share button rather than just text? Furthermore I'd like to ask how to get it to display the actual shares? The generic code at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/ does not answer this question. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `Share Button`. Facebook has `deprecated` this and this will no longer be supported. So, you have to use the `Share Dialog` instead that you've mentioned.